Can I use universal water heater thermocouple for brand 'American Standard' model G-50T1-3-6
I have water heater 'American Standard' G-50T1-3-6. I am almost sure thermocouple is done. Can I use those universal thermocouple that are sold in home depo and other like stores?

There are two types: a themopile, which generate a higher voltage, but at lower current, and thermocouple, which generates a higher current, but at lower voltage. Be sure it matches the type in your heater. See https://app.mycentriq.com/product-support/American+Standard/G-50T1-3-6+NAT/595a221c-ce77-4a7d-8abc-79154f1ef315 for manual.

Based on the photo I found of a pilot assembly for your model number, yes, I think it does incorporate a thermocouple in the pilot assembly. It isn't designed for replacement of the thermocouple alone but a universal thermocouple should be electrically compatible.
Note that there's a red rubber seal molded around the pilot tube, piezo wire, and thermocouple lead. This rubber on your existing part is likely to be old and crumbly. Extracting the old thermocouple and installing the new without damaging this seal beyond use may be challenging.
